# TYPO3 - inline f:section f:render dont work

Tags: typo3, fluid, fluid-layout, typo3-8.7.x

i have a problem with the inline f:render:

```
<f:section name="sysCategory">
    <f:for each="{sysCategoryDetailArray}" as="category" iteration="iteration">
        <f:spaceless>{category.title}</f:spaceless>
    </f:for>
</f:section>
```

Works:

```
<f:render section="sysCategory" arguments="{_all}" />
```

Dont Work:

```
{f:render(section: 'sysCategory', arguments: {_all})}
```

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{f:render(section: 'sysCategory', arguments: _all)}` is what you need.

Comment: JEAR! it works fine, thanks!!
{f:spaceless() -> f:render(section: 'sysCategory', arguments: _all)}

Comment: Chaining `f:spaceless` there does nothing - if you want the output of f:render to be passed through the spaceless formatter, you would need to do `{f:render(section: 'sysCategory', arguments: _all) -> f:spaceless()}`. The left hand side gets evaluated first, then passed as rendered child content to the next chain link, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to write either `arguments: variable` or `arguments: '{variable}'` when writing in inline syntax.